# How to get delegate to fire on CNContactPickerViewController() when predicateForSelectionOfContact causes selection of the contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, contacts

I'm trying to add phone selection to an iOS app using the Contacts API in iOS9.  It should call up the `CNContactsPickerViewController` and let the use choose only a contact which has at least one phone number associated.

If there are more than one phone number the user should be prompted to choose which one.

If there is only one, simply choosing the contact from the initial list should select the contact.

The behavior is almost correct.  I am not allowed to choose a contact with no phone number.  If I select a contact with multiple phones, I get prompted to choose one and the delegate is called.  If I select a contact with one phone number, it returns but no delegate is called.

I suspect I need to add a `NSPredicate` for `predicateForSelectionOfProperty` but I cannot find any format querying against the `CNContactProperty` which works.  If so, what's the appropriate predicate for `predicateForSelectionOfProperty` or if not, what am I missing?

```
- (void)initiateIdSelectionViaContacts
{
    CNContactPickerViewController *picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *propertyKeys = @[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactOrganizationNameKey];
    NSPredicate *enablePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(phoneNumbers.@count > 0)"];
    NSPredicate *contactSelectionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumbers.@count == 1"];

    picker.displayedPropertyKeys = propertyKeys;
    picker.predicateForEnablingContact = enablePredicate;
    picker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = contactSelectionPredicate;
    picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact
{
}

- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContactProperty:(CNContactProperty *)contactProperty
{
}
```